# How can i extract the location of organization in Freebase?

Tags: freebase

I am working with Freebase, I want to locate some organization from Freebase.

For example, I want to extract location (city, country, ...) from Cardiff University. For that I have made this query to view all properties of the entity:

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?
 query=
 [
    {"name":"cardiff%20university",
    "*":[{}],
    "type":"/education/university"}
 ]
```

[Link of query here](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=%5B%7B%22name%22%3a%22cardiff%20university%22,%22%2a%22%3a%5B%7B%7D%5D,%22type%22%3a%22/education/university%22%7D%5D)

But O do not see any field of location neither UK, Cardiff or something similar.

I think that Freebase has not got this information, but when I go to [webpage](http://www.freebase.com/view/en/cardiff_university), I can see   "Cardiff", "Wales"
and "United Kingdom".

How can I retrieve this information?

Answer (score 1):

When you use the * wildcard property you're asking for all the property values for the specified type which in this case is [/education/university](http://www.freebase.com/schema/education/university). The containedby property that you're looking for is part of [/location/location](http://www.freebase.com/schema/location/location) so it doesn't get shown.

There are two ways to show containedby in your query. One is to explicitly ask for that property using the full property path like this:

```
[{
  "name": "Cardiff University",
  "type": "/education/university",
  "/location/location/containedby": [{}]
}]​
```

The other way is to specify the default type as `/location/location` and then add the `/education/university` constraint using a prefix like this:

```
[{
  "name": "cardiff university",
  "*": [{}],
  "type": "/location/location",
  "f:type": "/education/university"
}]​
```